# Topelitz and matrix operators in $\ell_2$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $a,b$ satisfy $|a|,|b|<1$. We then define a vector $y = (\dots,b^2 ,b ,1 ,a ,a^2 ,\dots) \in \ell_ 1 (\mathbb{Z})$ with the ordering $y_0 = 1$.

We define a matrix operator $Y$ by $$Yx = \sum _{k=0}^\infty  \left( \sum_
{i=0}^\infty y_{i-k} x_i \right) e_k$$
Where $e_k$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell_2$.

I need to show that the matrix $Y$ defines a bounded operator in $\ell_2$
I have so far tried using triangle inequality together with Holder inequality and only came up with: $$ \|Yx\| \leq \|x\| \sum_k \sum_i |y_{i-k}|^2 $$ which does not converge (unless $a=b=0$).
Edit: I also thought of the similarity to laurent operators. the fourier coefficients of a multiplication operator define such a bounded operator, and so we can trace back a multiplication operator from a matrix, and with the "regular" isometry between $\ell_2$ and $L_2$ - such an operator must be well defined and bounded. However, i am not familiar with Topelitz operators and such analogies for them.

I would like a hint on this.

Another question regarding matrix operators: Sometimes - the sums arent written in a specific order: meaning you can invert the summation (if the matrix indeed represents a bounded operator). Why can this be done?

Comment: Is the fact that your sums start at $k=0$ and $i=0$, but we're considering sequences is $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ intentional?

Comment: @Roland Yes. Definng the operator with a sequence in $\ell_2 \mathbb Z$ was only a matter of convience

Comment: You can switch the order of summation here because $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty |y_{i-k}x_i| ≤\sum_{i=0}^\infty|x_i |\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}|y_{i-k}|≤ \sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i| \left(1+\frac{|a|}{1-|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1-|b|}\right) = ||x|| \left(1+\frac{|a|}{1-|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1-|b|}\right)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @s.harp The convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i|$ is unclear. The norm: $\|x\|$ satisfies: $\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i|^2 <\infty$

Comment: @Ranc oh right, we are in $\mathscr{l}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current definition if $Y$ is
$$
                 Yx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y_{i-k}x_{i}\right)e_{k}.
$$
Consider
\begin{align}
   \|Yx\|_2^2 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y_{i-k}x_{i}\right|^2 \\
  & \le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|y_{i-k}|||x_i|^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|y_{k-i}|\right) \\
  & \le \|y\|_1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|y_{k-i}||x_i|^2 \\
  & \le \|y\|_1\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|y_{k-i}||x_i|^2 \\
  & \le \|y\|_1^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|x_i|^2 = \|y\|_1^2\|x\|_2^2
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
                 \|Yx\|_2 \le \|y\|_1\|x\|_2 = \left(\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1-b}-1\right)\|x\|_2.
$$